# Type Cast String to Enum giving error in Apex

Tags: apex, enum

I am trying to convert String to an enum value. but I am getting null pointer exception.
Below is the code which I have tried to convert.
(I have checked other stackoverflow questions before asking the question)

```
public static Object parseEnum(String enumString, Type enumType) {
    Type cType = Type.forName(
        String.format('List<{0}>', new List<String>{ enumType.getName() })
    );
    System.debug('cType ' + cType); // throws null pointer exception
    return ((List<Object>) JSON.deserialize(
        String.format('["{0}"]', new List<String>{ enumString }),
        cType
    ))[0];
}

public enum Markup_Category {
    Admin,
    DC,
    Frozen
}
```

this is my methods which I am using to convert from String to Enum type. I am calling below code in the anonymous window for testing.

```
String markupCategory = 'Admin';
Markup_Category enumBoniMarkupCategory = (Markup_Category) parseEnum(
            markupCategory,
            Markup_Category.class
);
```

It is throwing null pointer exception at System.debug();.
If someone can help me what I am doing wrong or any other suggestions would be great.

PS: Please ignore any typo mistake as code is compelling correctly.

Comment: Im pretty sure the issue is coming from the `JSON.deserialize()` although Salesforce is reporting it on the `System.debug()`. If you remove the `JSON.deserialize()` , take a look at the output of your debug, I think you are getting a null `Type`.

Answer (score 4):

In testing this myself, I found that enumerations *and classes* declared inside of Anonymous Apex do not work with `Type.forName()` on any level. The following all return null:

- `Type.forName(String.format('List<{0}>', new List<Object>{MyEnum.class.getName()}));`
- `Type.forName('List<MyEnum>');`
- `Type.forName('MyEnum');`

If you save that enum as a proper class, the `parseEnum` method you provided should work as you expect when testing it from anonymous apex (even if `parseEnum` is itself defined in the anonymous apex window)
...provided the enum itself is visible (i.e. not private and being called from outside the class that would have visibility of it)

Comment: I had thought this myself, although it would be nice if Salesforce threw the exception in the right code block!

Comment: Thanks, @Derek for the reply but I have defined `Enum` in one of my class. I am only testing it through an anonymous window

Comment: @SagarHinsu Is that class saved as a proper apex class, or is the class defined in the anonymous window? If your enum is inside of a class, you need to add the outer class name as well (i.e. instead of using `Markup_Category.class`, you'd need to use `MyOuterClass.Markup_Category.class`)